# How should I handle hospitalization when I am about to start a new job?

Tags: new-job, sickness

I am supposed to start a job this Tuesday (Oct 29), but I had to go to the emergency room on Friday and won't be able to start on that day.

I am really looking forward to working in this new position so the timing is bad and I'm not sure how to properly communicate this to my new employer.  How should I communicate this to my future employer?

I am not exactly sure when I will be able to start, but most likely I can start the following Monday (Nov 4) so I will be absent only about a week.

Comment: Hi Sager, I edited your question somewhat to make it a bit more generic. Let me know if this changes your intent too much - great first question.

Comment: Note that in the US, you probably are not covered by the new employer's health insurance until after you start work. Of course we can't always choose when medical work is done.

Answer (score 16):

> Any advice you can give me would be greatly appreciated!!

You get on the phone as soon as the business day starts today or tomorrow, call your new boss and explain what happened.

You also explain that you don't yet know when you will be able to start, and explain that you will call them as soon as you do know.

There is nothing tricky about this. It isn't any different than if you were already on the payroll and had to go to the hospital.

Comment: Since the questioner is online and able to post questions to StackExchange I would recommend emailing *now* and also phoning as soon as the business day starts.

Comment: I would also offer  to bring proof of the hospital stay and any time your doctor says you can;t work after release from teh hospital. As a new emplyee, you haven't earned the trust of a long-time employee and this would go a long way towards making it clear you really are ill not just trying to push off your start date a week.

Answer (score 2):

You could also ask if there is information you could read online to prepare to start.  At our company, the first week is usually spent getting email and intranet logins set up, learning software, reading project documentation, learning the ins and outs of the office processes, etc. If there are conference calls for meetings that you are expected to attend, you could dial in from at home.